# Want to sort files by update date including sub-directories

Tags: ls

I want to sort only files by update dates including sub-directories.

I found out `ls -lrtR | grep ^-`. but it doesn't seem to sort by update dates.

And I need to save this list into a file. Is it possible?

```
Apr 01 2010  InsideDoosanServiceImpl.class  // in A directory
Apr 08 2010  MainController.class  // in B directory
Apr 07 2010  RecommendController.class  // in B directory
Apr 01 2010  MainDao.class  // in B directory
```

I mean the whole list is not ordered by date, but first ordered by folder, and ordered by date.

I want a list first ordered by date including all sub-directories.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I am not sure what exactly do you mean by `update dates`, but you are using `-r` option which according to man does this -

> -r
> Reverse the order of the sort to get reverse lexicographical order or the oldest entries first (or largest files last, if combined with sort by size

I think this should be good enough for you if you need files sorted by time.

`ls -lRt`

If you don't need all the other stuff listed by `ls` then you can use -

`ls -1Rt`

To capture the result in a file, you can use the redirection operator `>` and give a file name. So you can do something like this -

`ls -lRt > sortedfile.list`

#### Update:

```
find . -type f -exec ls -lt {} +
```

This will sort files so that the newest files are listed first. To reverse the sort order, showing newest files at the end, use the following command:

```
find . -type f -exec ls -lrt {} +
```

Comment: I mean the last time a file was modified :)

Comment: Sort result is ordered by folder and date. I want to sort by date and folder.. is it possible?

Comment: Sorry, can you please show me some output? I didn't quite follow the sorting of folder if you used `ls -lrt`.

Comment: //Jaypal Singh, I updated my output to my quiestion ↑ :). I really hope you understand it and sorry for my bad English.

Comment: No worries, I have added an alternative. Hope that helps.

Comment: Sorry, but it says `0652-017 -printf is not a valid option.`.

Comment: OS version is `AIX 6.1`.

Comment: Looks like you don't have `GNU find` on your system. Try the new one.

Comment: It perfectly works. I really appreciate your help.!

Comment: I am glad it worked out. :)

Comment: This fails if the file list is sufficiently long to force `xargs` to make multiple calls to `ls`, because then the files are only properly sorted within each `ls` invocation but lack a coherent global order in the output.

Comment: @BrandonRhodes How long does the list need to be for `find` to invoke `ls` multiple times?

Comment: It would depend on OS, on kernel parameters that set various buffer sizes, perhaps on buffer sizes compiled into `find`, and probably on how large the filenames were (as long filenames would fill the buffers first). I would expect that only experiments would let you set firm bounds for your OS.

Answer (score 24):

With ls, -R will recurse directories and -t will sort by modification.  However, it traverses directories recursively and applies -t to each directory.  It doesn't accumulate all files from all directories and then sort.  (As far as I understand, the latter is what you want)

With gnu find(1) you can specify the format of output to include the number of seconds since epoch and the filename, then you can pipe this to sort(1).

```
find . -type f -printf "%T@ %f\n" | sort -n > out.txt
```

Comment: Yea `GNU find` does help. But OP works on `AIX` machines so `GNU find` wasn't available to him.

Comment: It's too bad `ls` can't be made to accumulate files before sorting. `ls` is *so fast* compared to `find`.

Comment: `ls` and `find` reads the same data, so I can't imagine any reason ls should be considerably faster than find. On my system find is 5 times faster (searching through roughly half a million files)

Comment: You might want a full date/time and not only the file name but also the path in the output, in that case, modify the formatting string: `find . -type f -printf "%T@ %Tc %p\n" | sort -n > out.txt` yielding output entries like `1427913836.2330520210 wed  1 apr 2015 20:43:56 ./subdir/file.txt`.

Comment: Great. That really helped me out. I've been looking for a way to sort into subdirectories for ages!